# PHP method for specific Facebook meta-tags works itself but doesn't on Facebook platform

Tags: php, facebook, dynamic, path, meta-tags

i needed specific facebook open graph meta-tags for some pages of my website.

My website is based on a PHP "include" structure. In order to make specific tags for each page, I wrote a PHP code that reads the file that is going to be included and extract the specific tags. Like this, authors can just easily set specific tags in their page and I have no necessity to create a database for fb meta-tags only.

```
<?php

// DEFAULT TAGS
$fbtitle = 'GB';
$fbimage = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/logo.jpg';
$fbdesc = 'bla bla.';

// READ THE FILE TO BE INCLUDED
$lines = file($sezioni[$controllo1]);
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
if(strstr($line, '$fb') && strstr($line, '='))
{               
eval($line);                
}
}
?>

<meta property="og:title" content="<?php print $fbtitle ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php print $fbimage ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php print $fbdesc ?>" />
```

It works on the website itself. It doesn't on facebook and Facebook Developers. For some reason Facebook automatically terminate the  section before the beginning of this php script. And, what's more, it gives this error with the "file()".

```
Warning: file(): Filename cannot be empty in /web/htdocs/www.grandisperanze.com/home/testa.php on line 21
```

A path/dir_root problem?

Comment: Okay, as I shall say, I'm an idiot. Part of my website is based on $_GET and in the fb url meta-tag i just wrote down the default url of my website (http://www.mywebsite.com). A "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" makes facebook redirect the $_GET and so on. Everything now works. Thanks anyway, Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook automatically redirects $_GET correctly and my website was based on it.

Anyway, I did not noticed that and I set the og:url Facebook meta-tag on something default (like "http://www.mywebsite.it"). This was the error.

The solution is to use  in the og:url meta-tag.